# Translation error in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I enabled translation option into my Bot configuration but each time I send requests to change language like:

"I would like to speak spanish"

"Voglio parlare in inglese"

I get always the following message:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  [jlxRaNQ9xP]*

Thanks,

Comment: Got to bot connector and in the "Test connection to your bot" zone test it.

Comment: @CodeNotFound It sometimes works other not. It seems to work into "Test connection" box, but not from clients. You can try ten times and it works may be two times.
It seems a problem related to platform. Do you know if there is a way to send a notification to developing team?

Comment: Send email to bf-reports@microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")` in your bot application (Bot SDK v4.0).